# Why doesn't this assert work - assertThat(foo, is(not(null)));

Tags: java, hamcrest

This assertion compiles but fails even though I know for a fact that foo is not null:

```
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.is;  // see http://stackoverflow.com/a/27256498/2848676
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

...

```
assertThat(foo, is(not(null)));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## **tl;dr**

your assert doesn't work, because you call `not(Matcher<T> matcher)` with `null` matcher. Use a sortcut, instead:

```
    assertThat(foo, notNullValue());
```

### the shortcut:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.notNullValue;
    ...
    assertThat(foo, notNullValue());
```

credits to @eee

### the canonical form:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.nullValue;
    ...
    assertThat(foo, not( nullValue() ));
```

### your (OP) approach:

```
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.not;
    ...
    assertThat(foo, not( (Foo)null ));
```

The type casting is required here, in order to don't confuse `not(T value)` with `not(Matcher<T> matcher)`.
REF: http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html

Answer (score 12):

Empirically, I've found that this works instead:

```
assertThat(foo, is(not(nullValue())));
```

Comment: There is even a own method for this: `Matchers.notNullValue()`.