# How to make JUnit assertThat() work with lower bounded wildcard?

Tags: java, generics, junit, assertthat

initially, I had this piece of production code:

```
interface ActionSequence {
   public List<Actions> getActions();
```

I tested classes implementing that interface with something like this:

```
assertThat(sequenceUnderTest.getActions(), is(Arrays.asList(action1, action2));
```

Then I figured that it might be beneficial to change the production interface to:

```
public List<? extends Action> getActions() {
```

(to allow me to return lists of subclasses of Action).

But now eclipse tells me:

```
The method assertThat(T, Matcher<? super T>) in the type Assert is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#1-of ? extends Action>, Matcher<List<Action>>)
```

I figured: when I change the **class** that implements ActionInterface to do

```
@Override
public List<SomeSubClassOfAction> getActions()
```

(instead of keeping the wildcard) ... then everything works. But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(action1, action2)` will return a `List<Action>`.
`is(Arrays.asList(action1, action2))` will therefore return a `Matcher<List<Action>>`.

assertThat has the following signature:

```
assertThat(T actual, Matcher<T> matcher)
```

So assertThat requires the following parameters in your case:

```
assertThat(List<Action>, Matcher<List<Action>>)
```

But your first parameter is a `List<? extends Action>`
And a `List<Action>` is completely different from a `List<? extends Action>`.
For example, you cannot put Action elements into a `List<SomeSubClassOfAction>`. 
This is why this won't work.

For details, see Angelika Langer's excellent site: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/Index.html

Comment: also note that what I wrote is true as of JUnit 4.8.2. In JUnit 4.11, the assertThat signature has been changed to assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher). In this case, your code will compile.

Comment: Similarly, is(Arrays.asList(action1, action2)) will return  a Matcher<List<? extends Action>>. In this case, your code will compile, so I suppose you used some version before JUnit 4.11. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256429/is-org-junit-assert-assertthat-better-than-org-hamcrest-matcherassert-assertthat for details on this JUnit change

Comment: Probably I have to dig deeper; but I think my eclipse is running with 4.11 (that is the JUnit jar that is checked into our "production" project repository). Strange.

Comment: You could simply check what type of object is(Arrays.asList(action1, action2)) returns...

Answer (score 1):

Your question was, why

```
@Override
public List<SomeSubClassOfAction> getActions()
```

is a legal Implementation of

```
public List<? extends Action> getActions()
```

The Answer is *covariant return*. Since Java1.5 subclasses are allowed to specialize the return of inherited methods.

But I wouldn't recommend having wildcard types in return parameters because it isn't client friendly. See [Generic wildcard types should not be used in return parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815023) and its quote from *Effective Java*